# Simple web service using Amazon SES

Tags: java, ruby, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I would like to use AWS and especially Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) in order to setup a webservice allowing to send emails.

Emails would be triggered by some kind of POST request to the webservice with some authentication, and the webservice would then just send the email on behalf of the web service user.

Where should I start? The webservice part looks dead simple but I'm not familiar at all with web services. I still need to run some kind of multithreaded webserver since there could be a bunch of concurrent requests.

Is there a way for me to write a very simple web server in Ruby or Java to do that? Any pointer appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, the simplest solution is to use something like node.js or sinatra. The nice thing is that these are almost self-contained and require barely any configuration. They provide a very easy way to reply to HTTP requests.

Once you get one of these, you start the script with a port.

The small webservice will now listen on that port. You only need to take action based on the requests passed as parameter.

And yeah, now it sounds so obvious...

Answer (score 1):

their documentation is good way to start. its quite easy to start, may encounter difficulties based on your problem domains.
you also need to implement something on top of this service.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/APIReference/
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with looking at AWS sdk Java.
They seem to support SES.
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. But actually the part I'm missing is how to implement the server part of the web service. The logic itself doesn't worry me but more how to have something that can serve the requests as they arrive and apply the logic to each of them.